# Stumped with sentinal controlled repetition logic from deitals how to program9th. Q 4.18

Tags: java

Hi this is my solution to what seems to be an easy question. just take some data from user calculate whether the user has exceeded his limit and display a message if so. I have used sentinel-controlled repetition. I can exit the program the first time round by entering -1. However after that it doesn't work and I can't exit the program. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CreditLimitCalculator {

  public void getNewBalance(){

    int acc;
    int oldBal;
    int debit;
    int credit;
    int limit;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter account number or -1 to exit");
    acc = input.nextInt();

    while (acc != -1){
        System.out.println("Enter old balance");
        oldBal = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter total debits");
        debit = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter total credit");
        credit = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Limit");
        limit = input.nextInt();

        int newBalance = oldBal + credit - debit;

        if (newBalance < limit){
            System.out.println("Credit Limit exceeded");

        }
    }
 }
}
```

I changed the code to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreditLimitCalculator {

  public void getNewBalance(){

    int acc;
    int oldBal;
    int debit;
    int credit;
    int limit;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter account number or -1 to exit");
    acc = input.nextInt();

    while (acc != -1){
        System.out.println("Enter old balance");
        oldBal = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter total debits");
        debit = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter total credit");
        credit = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Limit");
        limit = input.nextInt();

        int newBalance = oldBal + credit - debit;

        if (newBalance < limit){
            System.out.println("Credit Limit exceeded");

            System.out.println("Enter account number or -1 to exit");
            acc = input.nextInt();

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Which now works if the balance is less than the limit and the message gets displayed saying credit Limit exceded, but if the if statement is not true, i.e the account balance does nort exceed the limit it seems to skip the last 2 lines of code and jump straight back to "enter new balance. Which I don't understand because the 2 new lines I added seem to be within the which statement

Comment: "after that it doesn't work": what *should* it do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: each time it gets to the bottom of the which statement it should ask for account number and ask the user to press -1 to exit if required, but it only seems to execute those last 2 lines of code if the limit is exceded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is based on the value in `acc`, which never changes in the loop.

*Update*: I fixed the indentation of your code; the new problem you describe should have an obvious fix now.

Comment: Thanks this helped me towards an answer but it still doesn't work in all cases

Comment: Thanks you were right it was obvious as soon as you indented it cheers!